# AppCompat v21 lollipop material design

Tags: android, styles, toolbar, android-appcompat, material-design

I using Toolbar widget in my application here is my output now the toolbar il almost been cropped cause of the status bar but when i set windowTranslucentStatus to false the output will be perfect but still my status bar is not coloured here is my style code:

```
enter code here

  <style name="Badge_Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Use the Toolbar instead of the ActionBar
         (new in API 21 and AppCompat). -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>

    <!-- Set AppCompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it. The toolbar needs some spacing for the status bar. So do this:

In values\styles.xml add this line 0dp

Then in values-v21\styles.xml add this:  25dp

Now finally, in your toolbar.xml add  android:paddingTop="@dimen/topMargin"

This should give you the spacing you desire.

**EDIT:**

Assuming you have setup your Toolbar to be the ActionBar in your Activity, remove this line in your styles.xml
   `<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>`

You could also remove android:windowTranslucentStatus and android:windowTranslucentNavigation. I dont see why you need it.

If you are using AppCompat, then remove the 'android:' prefix.

For more information. Check out this relevant
[link.](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)

Comment: The padding method did not solve my issue it only made the badge word comes down only my problem is that the toolbar itself is covering the status bar or vice versa how can this be done what iam missing in my style @Suleiman19

Comment: If your using the new toolbar, why are you using 'actionBarStyle'? Remove that line.

Also you could try adding this
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/yourcolor</item>

Comment: i did what you said but nothing changed 
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item> this line is responsible for the status bar thing if i set it to true it will cover the toolbar if i set to false status bar will be with no color sounds confusing @Suleiman19

Comment: windowTranslucentStatus makes your status bar partially transparent and makes the content below it overlap the status bar. What is it that you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: If you see my 2 images above the result showing that the status bar is overlapping my toolbar i don't want that i want it exactly below it just like the second picture but instead of the status bar color black i need it purple @Sulmeiman19